# Is there a base strip method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

I have this snippet of code that I intend to use to get the first and last name from a CSV file to get a specific output. The end goal is to have the last name and first and last letter of the first name in the username.

The CSV file I have has First name and Last name Headers.

Example:

First Name John Last Name: Doe Desired output: doejn

What the first two lines of the CSV file look like:

```
First Name:        Last Name:
John               Doe
```

Code that I have:

```
require 'csv'

filename = 'employeedata.csv'

CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
   first_name_char = row['First Name'].strip.split('')
   useradd_name = "#{row['Last Name']}#{first_name_char.first}#{first_name_char.last}"
   puts useradd_name
end
```

Desired output:

```
DoeJn
```

When I do this it errors out.

This is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from Nick_Hyder_Project3.rb:17:in `<main>'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:509:in `foreach'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:657:in `open'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:510:in `block in foreach'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:1236:in `each'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv.rb:1236:in `each'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:303:in `parse'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:779:in `parse_quotable_loose'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:28:in `each_line'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:28:in `each_line'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:31:in `block in each_line'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:827:in `block in parse_quotable_loose'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/csv/parser.rb:1078:in `emit_row'
Nick_Hyder_Project3.rb:18:in `block in <main>': undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is the error caused by me not having a correct lib required? Will it error out because I don't have an array to store the new usernames?

Comment: Hopefully edits shows the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because `row['First Name']` is getting evaluated to `nil`. Please check your column names properly and make sure the value of `row['First Name']` is getting evaluated properly.

You may need to escape the `space` in `row['First Name']`

Answer (score 2):

Let's first construct the file.

```
str =<<~END
First Name:        Last Name:
John               Doe
Mary               Smith
END
```

```
FName = 't.csv'
File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 78
```

Let's confirm the file contents.

```
puts File.read(FName)
First Name:        Last Name:
John               Doe
Mary               Smith
```

The difficulty is that you have one field separator for the headers (a colon followed by a variable number of spaces) and another for each line of the body (spaces only). That is not a valid CSV file format. Accordingly, it's best to merely treat it as an ordinary text file and not attempt to employ CSV methods.

```
first_line, *rest = File.readlines(FName)
  #=> ["First Name:        Last Name:\n",
  #    "John               Doe\n",
  #    "Mary               Smith\n"]
```

This yields the following:

```
first_line
  #=> "First Name:        Last Name:\n"
rest
  #=> ["John               Doe\n",
  #    "Mary               Smith\n"]
```

Now convert `rest` to a more convenient form:

```
arr = rest.map { |line| line.scan(/\S+/) }
  #=> [["John", "Doe"], ["Mary", "Smith"]]
```

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan). The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters that are not whitespaces". A space and newline (`"\n"`) are both whitespaces.

If we know that first names come before the last names in each line of the file, we can continue to obtain the desired result. If we don't know that, however, we can do the following:

```
arr.map!(&:reverse) if first_line.start_with?("Last Name:")
```

If the first line were instead `"Last Name:         First Name:\n"` and the two names in each line of the body were reversed, this would convert `arr` to the desired form:

```
[["John", "Doe"], ["Mary", "Smith"]]
```

Lastly, we need only convert `arr` to the desired result:

```
arr.map { |first_name, last_name| last_name + first_name[0] +
  first_name[-1] }
  #=> ["DoeJn", "SmithMy"]
```

This would of course have to be adjusted if a first name could consist of a single character or if a person might have no first name (e.g., "Cher").

Note `arr.map!(&:reverse)` is effectively shorthand for `arr.map! { |a| a.reverse }`.

The method [IO::readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-readlines)<sup>1</sup> *gulps* the file into an array. If the file is sufficiently large, however, there might be insufficient available memory to do that. In that case one must read the file line-by-line. One way of doing that is as follows.

```
first_line_read = false
File.foreach(FName).with_object([]) do |line, arr|
  if first_line_read == false
    first_name_first = line.start_with?("First Name:")       
    first_line_read = true
    next
  end
  a = line.scan(/\S+/)
  a.reverse! unless first_name_first
  arr << (a.last + a.first[0] + a.first[-1])
end
  #=> ["JohnDe", "MarySh"]
```

<sup>1. It is common practice to invoke `IO` methods with `File` as the receiver. That is permissible because `File` is a subclass of `IO`.</sup>